# What will be the result for the dropWhile in scala

Tags: scala

I am using dropWhile in scala below is my problem.
Problem:

```
val list = List(87, 44, 5, 4, 200)
list.dropWhile(_ < 100) should be(/*result*/)
```

My Answer:

```
val list = List(87, 44, 5, 4, 200)
list.dropWhile(_ < 100) should be(List(44,5,4,200))
```

As per the documentation on dropWhile will continually drop elements until a predicate is no longer satisfied:
In my list the first element will satisfy the predicate so i removed the first element from the list.

```
val list = List(87, 44, 5, 4, 200)
list.dropWhile(_ < 100) should be(/*result*/)
```

I am expecting a result of `List(44,5,4,200)`
But it is not.

Comment: The doc literally said *continually drop* elements until a predicate is no longer satisfied

Comment: "... until the predicate is no longer satisfied." `44` satisfies the predicate. `5` satisfies the predicate. Etc.

Comment: read this function as "drop/remove elements while condition is true, stop when it's no longer true".

Answer (score 7):

You are kind of going in the wrong direction. The head of the list is 87.  The next element is 44, etc. `dropWhile` will continue to drop elements from the list until it hits that 200. If you initialize the list with more elements to the right of the 200, say

```
val list = List(87, 44, 5, 4, 200, 54, 60)
```

Then `list.dropWhile(_ < 100)` will return `dropped: List[Int] = List(200, 54, 60)`